# Copying a list of test/path/to/files to list of prod/path/to/files

Tags: command-line, cp, xargs

I would like to copy a list of files in the form `test/path/to/file/filename.xyz` to their corresponding production path `prod/path/to/file/filename.xyz`.  If the test path and the prod path are the same except for the presence of "prod" instead of "test", can I use the following command?  Will this overwrite the destination file?

```
$ xargs -I % --arg-file=input.txt cp  /test/%  /prod/%
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your use of `xargs`, and particularly the meaning of `%`.

But about `cp`, yes it will overwrite the destination files. However, `cp` has several options to take care of this:

- `-b` or `--backup[=CONTROL]` : make a backup of each existing destination file
- `-i` or `--interactive` : prompt before overwrite (overrides a previous -n option)
- `-n` or `--no-clobber` : do not overwrite an existing  file
- `-u` or `--update` : copy only when the SOURCE file is  newer than  the destination file or when the destination file is missing

See `man cp` for more.

As for your ultimate goal, I think that what you mean is to copy some files under "test/" listed in your `input.txt` file, to the same path under "prod/". For that, it seems `rsync` might be better suited. It has tons of options. A few of those which may be relevant :

> ```
> -b, --backup            make backups (see --suffix & --backup-dir)
> --backup-dir=DIR        make backups into hierarchy based in DIR
> --suffix=SUFFIX         backup suffix (default ~ w/o --backup-dir)
> --files-from=FILE       read list of source-file names from FILE
> -R, --relative`         use relative path names
> -u, --update            skip files that are newer on the receiver
> -n, --dry-run           perform a trial run with no changes made
> [etc]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using `--files-from=` option with `rsync` allows you to specify the exact list of files to transfer:

```
$ rsync -av --ignore-existing \
  --files-from=input.txt test/ prod/
```